# How can I stop an unfocused Xamarin Forms Picker from receiving keyboard events?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and a Picker.
The picker acts as a filter for a Telerik grid on a ContentPage with a distinct list of column values.

I am handling the OnKeyDown event in MainActivity for an Android based device with a trigger.
The trigger sends an F9 key event when depressed.
I capture this event to perform a device specific function.

The problem is when I select from the picker or press cancel, the picker still receives the OnKeyDown event and apparently handles it before it can be dispatched and handled by the overridden handler in MainActivity.  The only way to stop this behavior is to tap on the grid before depressing the trigger.

I can firm that the picker's IsFocused property shows false but it still receives the event.

Will I need to use a custom renderer on the picker to solve this issue? TIA

Comment: You can got the focus in the picker's custom renderer with `Control?.ClearFocus();`, please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564919/custom-renderer-for-picker-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

In your OnKeyDown event handler, check whether picker has focus. If it does not, return `false` from the handler to indicate that you have not handled the event. The system will then give another handler a chance to handle the event. If the only other handler is in MainActivity, then the MainActivity handler will get called.